# Java MySQLに情報を追加する処理について

Tags: java, mysql

データ操作するクラス

```
public class Toi3_db {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws SQLException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Member mem = new Member(11,"yamasaki","yamasaki@mail.com");
        Connection con = (new DBConnection()).getConnection();
        MemberCtrl memctrl = new MemberCtrl(con);
        boolean ret = memctrl.excuteInsert(mem);

        if(ret == false){
            //失敗したときの出力処理
            System.out.println("INSERT失敗：");
        }
    }
}
```

---

処理するクラス

```
public class MemberCtrl {

    public boolean excuteInsert(Member mem) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException {
        try{
            //SQL文を定義する
            String sql="INSERT INTO T_MEMBER(id ,name, email) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            System.out.println("a");
            //実行するSQL文とパラメータを指定する
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            System.out.println("b");
            ps.setInt(1, 11);
            ps.setString(2, "yamasaki");
            ps.setString(3, "yamasaki@mail.com");

            //INSERT文を実行する
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }finally{
            if(con!=null){
                con.close();
            }   
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

---

実行すると

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at MemberCtrl.excuteInsert(MemberCtrl.java:46)
>     at Toi3_db.main(Toi3_db.java:21)

Toi3_db.java:21は　       `boolean ret = memctrl.excuteInsert(mem);`
MemberCtrl.java:46は     `ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);`

なぜ起きたでしょうか？ 宜しくお願い致します。

#### 追記：

ありがとうございます。コンストラクタを入れてさきのエラーは解決しました。 
しかし今度は

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
>   at ctrl.MemberCtrl.excuteInsert(MemberCtrl.java:66)
>   at Toi3_db.main(Toi3_db.java:21)

MemberCtrl.java:66 は `ps.setInt(1, 11);`
Toi3_db.java:21 は `boolean ret = memctrl.excuteInsert(mem);`

というエラーが出てきました。なぜでしょうか？

Comment: stack traceに表示されているとおりで、 ps=con.prepareStatement(sql); のconがnullなのでは？

Comment: `MemberCtrl` を new する際に Connection con を渡しているようですが、コンストラクタの中で正しく処理されていないのではないですか？ `MemberCtrl` のコンストラクタも提示してください。

Comment: Connection con = (new DBConnection()).getConnection(); この時点でconがnullの可能性もありますね。

Comment: ありがとうございます
nullを解決致しました。

Answer (score 1):

追記されたエラーは preparedStatement が受け取れるパラメータ数が 0 なのにsetInt()でparameter Index に 1 が指定されたということを表しています。つまり指定したSQLに何らかの誤りがある可能性が高いです。

MySQLは環境や設定次第でテーブル名の大文字小文字を区別しますが、そのあたりは提示のソースと一致していますか？